# Ejecutar un servicio programado en NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, plesk

Instale un paquete llamado interval-promise y funciona perfectamente, ejecuta y después de 3 segundos vuelve y ejecuta la función, pero después de cierto tiempo que no he podido determinar aún, el programa deja de funcionar a no ser que ingrese a una URL que tuve que crear que simplemente devuelve un 200 no hace más, eso reactiva de nuevo el servicio, y sigue ejecutándose. Lo intente solucionar creando un llamado cada 30 minutos a la URL que cree pero no funciona a no ser que ingrese manualmente, ¿hay alguna forma de hacer que ese servicio corra permanentemente?

El código es el siguiente:

```
server.start(() => {
interval(async () => {
    await SoccerApi.listenForEvents();
}, 3000)});
```

Y en Plesk la tarea programada la tengo de la siguiente forma:

[image: Cron]

Notas adicionales:

Versión Node => 12.4.0

Versión Plesk => 18.0.24

Versión interval-promise => 1.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré el error, era que en el ambiente de producción estaba ejecutando el comando de nodemon más no el de node, ese era el error detectaba cambios y se reiniciaba el servidor y no ejecutaba hasta que se realizara una petición al server